# Maximum sampling rate of Arduino Mega2560

Tags: atmega2560

I'd like to know what is the maximum sampling rate achievable while using ADC on Arduino Mega2560.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of section 26 of the [datasheet for the ATMega2560](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) gives the following data:

> • 13µs - 260µs Conversion Time
>   • Up to 76.9kSPS (Up to 15kSPS at Maximum Resolution)